# How to change the text size in a Kivy TwoLineAvatarIconListItem?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I´ve the following ky file , but I´m not able to change the text size. Any help will be apreciated.

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    MDScrollView:
        MDList:
            md_bg_color: 1, .5, .5, .4
            OneLineAvatarListItem:
                text: 'just a text msg'
                font_size: '50dp'
                IconLeftWidget:
                    icon: 'plus'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `font_style` instead of `font_size`. For example:

```
font_style: 'H1'
```

Possible values for `font_style` are defined by:

```
theme_font_styles = [
    "H1",
    "H2",
    "H3",
    "H4",
    "H5",
    "H6",
    "Subtitle1",
    "Subtitle2",
    "Body1",
    "Body2",
    "Button",
    "Caption",
    "Overline",
    "Icon",
]
```